# How to count months and years in one variable?

Tags: static, decimalformat

So I'm currently working on a simulator that stores the years and months as two seperate variables, like so:

```
static double currentYear = 1;
static double currentMonth = 1;
```

And it updates like this:

```
if(currentMonth == 12){
currentYear++;
currentMonth = 1;
}else{
currentMonth++;
}
```

I am pretty unfamiliar with the DecimalFormat class, but I know that it would be possible to create an output that read Year: ####, Month: ##, but the problem I am encountering is that it would have to obviously add a year every twelve months instead of ten, like normal digits.
Is there an easier way of computing this or is my way the easiest?

Comment: Why you have tagged it as sql? static double is not in sql!!!

Comment: I don't know it reccomended sql and I didn't really know what else to tag it as so yeah I apologize.

Comment: This would be really surprising for many people here that you dont know the language in which you are facing the problem or in which you are coding!

Comment: Why not use a `Date` type and just add a month each time?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom type to represent your duration in years and months. Something like this:

```
class YearMonthDuration
{
  private int durationInMonths ;

  public int Years  { get { return durationInMonths / 12 ; } }
  public int Months { get { return durationInMonths % 12 ; } }

  public YearMonthDuration( int years , int months )
  {
    this.durationInMonths = years * 12 + months ;
    return ;
  }

  public static explicit operator int( YearMonthDuration instance )
  {
    return instance.Years*100 + instance.Months ;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("Years={0}/Months={1}" , Years , Months ) ;
  }

  public YearMonthDuration AddYears( int years )
  {
    durationInMonths += years*12 ;
    return this ;
  }
  public YearMonthDuration AddMonths( int months )
  {
    durationInMonths += months ;
    return this ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the time-space trade of. Waste computer cycles to store more data.
In the same way time is stored on many computers - UNIX Timestamp which counts the number of seconds since the epoch and then you calculate the date from it, in a similar manner you can store your months and years. Just use a single integer to store the total number of months and then when outputting just use

```
"Year: " + floor(totalMonths/12) + " Month: " + ((totalMonths % 12) + 1);
```

Where % is the modulus operator (i.e. can be mod or something similar depending on your language of choice) and floor is just a function that rounds down to the lower integer.

BTW formatting is another issue you can look up on the internet, plenty of guides for it.